# How to setup mongo-kafka-connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am not using confluent, I am able to run the Zookeeper and `Kafka` successfully. And following the steps to `Mongo-kafka` connect using jar file and am getting an error. Once I download the `mongo-kafka-connect-0.2-all.jar` file from maven tech do I need to register? I have updated the plugin path correctly. can someone help me, please?

```
com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnectorINFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:56)
[2019-10-22 03:16:02,713] ERROR Failed to create job for config/MongoSinkConnector.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110)
[2019-10-22 03:16:02,714] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error because Kafka Connect has not loaded the connector JAR that you're trying to use :

```
Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
```

One option you have is to use the [Confluent Hub tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html#installing-c-hub-client) to install the connector - you can you use it without running Confluent Platform IIRC:

```
confluent-hub install mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:0.2
```

The Confluent Hub tool handles stuff like `plugin.path` automagically so that you don't have to.

Alternatively, you can configure it yourself. Make sure `plugin.path` for your Kafka Connect worker(s) is set to include the folder in which you have the MongoDB sink connector JAR.